# How to set base api url in angular 2 client without angular CLI for multiple environment

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core

I'm building an app with angular 2 and .net core (with some .net framework 4.6 -please don't ask)

Everything runs fine until I need to deploy to the test server where the app will be hosted as a subfolder (http://devserver/myapp), so now my api calls are calling the root (http://devserver/api/...) instead of my api (http://devserver/myapp/api)

I'm looking for something that works like the environments folder of Angular CLI, but I can't since I'm using Dotnet and webpack.

It must work for all http request not only get requests.

How can I set a url configuration on the client?
Thanks

Comment: Why not set it on the server? Use a Razor View (or Razor Page if you are on ASP.NET Core >=2.0) as entry for your application and set `<base href="~/"/>`. `~` in Razor pages href/src attributes will be interpreted as application root and hence all urls beginning with `~` will be relative to the application

Comment: you are right, setting the base href works, my mistake was that I had a slash at the begining of my api path.
found the complete solution here https://long2know.com/2016/04/angular-root-path-and-iis-express/